# ASP.Net core 2/ Program doesn't show exception page while running

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a problem to show exception page in a browser when I debugging, it's important to me to know the details about the error because I know something doesn't work properly. Even I set in Environment Variables, `value = Development`. And my `startup.cs` looks:`

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env) {
    if (env.IsDevelopment()) {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    } else {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
}
```

I tried to use try-catch blocks and just throw new Exception to see if this work. And both methods didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

I was running into a similar issue that was caused by a bad request. It was showing a blank page but adding the line above showed the status code.

Also, if you use the "project" launch profile, and start the project instead of using IIS Express, it will have detailed logging in the console which might help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried middleware to trap exceptions?

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brandonh/2017/07/31/using-middleware-to-trap-exceptions-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: No, I haven't. I will try your approach.

Answer (score 0):

When you throw exceptions, are you using this code ? It's working fine for me :

```
throw new ApplicationException("") ;
```

Comment: Your example works fine when I throw my own exception but still, I can't display errors in my app. When I put a breakpoint in a method which I know work unproperly and track step by step I can't get info about what is wrong.

Comment: Did you set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development in your actuel session ?

Comment: Yes, but the reason why this didn't work was in different place :)